# Matching fixed letter with dynamic numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do you preg_match fixed letters with a dynamic number?

E.g.

```
#^[1-9][0-9]*$#
```

Is the code to fetch two numbers the start of any string e.g. 1 and 0

What i'm trying to do is match all the strings of a file that look like...r00,r01,r02,r03...and so forth until e.g. r999

What i tried doing is

```
#r^[1-9][0-9]*$#
```

*This is done using Preg_Match

However it doesn't work. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: `^`  =  start of string, `r^` logically means _"'r' followed by the start of a string"_ , which is logically impossible. You probably want something like `#^r[0-9]{0,3}$#` (you seem to want to allow a starting `0` as well, so drop the `[1-9]` start).

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern if you want to stop at `r999`:

```
#^r[0-9]{2,3}$#
```

This will match:

- the start of the string (`^`)
- a literal `r`
- two or three digits from 0 to 9
- the end of the string (`$`)

Or this pattern if there is no upper limit—i.e. `r999999` is acceptable:

```
#^r[0-9]{2,}$#
```

This will match:

- the start of the string (`^`)
- a literal `r`
- two or more digits from 0 to 9
- the end of the string (`$`)

Comment: Your code will not match `r0x` like OP requested:`r00,r01,r02,r03...and so forth until e.g. r999`

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern:

```
#^r\d{2,3}$#
```

See [explanation](http://regex101.com/r/kG0jP0).

Answer (score 0):

`^` means "start of line", unless it's used within brackets, when it means "everything except the follow characters".

You want something like `#r\d{2,3}#`, optionally with a `^` first, or `$` last (excepting the hashes).

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents:

```
\br\d{1,3}\b
```

it will match r0,r00,r01,r02,r03...r999 but not `r\d{4,}`